# Hibernate + JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've got a project of mine in which I would like to take advantage of Hibernate to increase the speed of development for basic operations, combined with Spring's JDBC template to be able to use my own SQL queries for some specific operations and not loose control, since there are some heavy, performance demanding operations.

Is this even possible or a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. And yes, it's a good idea.

[The documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-hibernate-tx-strategies) says:

> For distributed transactions across multiple Hibernate session factories, simply combine JtaTransactionManager as a transaction strategy with multiple LocalSessionFactoryBean definitions. Each DAO then gets one specific SessionFactory reference passed into its corresponding bean property. If all underlying JDBC data sources are transactional container ones, a business service can demarcate transactions across any number of DAOs and any number of session factories without special regard, as long as it is using JtaTransactionManager as the strategy.

[...]

> HibernateTransactionManager can export the Hibernate JDBC Connection to plain JDBC access code, for a specific DataSource. This capability allows for high-level transaction demarcation with mixed Hibernate and JDBC data access completely without JTA, if you are accessing only one database. HibernateTransactionManager automatically exposes the Hibernate transaction as a JDBC transaction if you have set up the passed-in SessionFactory with a DataSource through the dataSource property of the LocalSessionFactoryBean class. Alternatively, you can specify explicitly the DataSource for which the transactions are supposed to be exposed through the dataSource property of the HibernateTransactionManager class.

So, if you're in a full-stack Java EE container supporting JTA transactions and DataSources, use a DataSource defined in your Java EE container and a JTATransactionManager.

If you'e in a simple web container such as Tomcat, use a Spring-provided DataSource and a HibernatTransactionManager.

Comment: what would be the difference (in terms of performance) between using Hibernate's executeSQL and using JSBCTemplate (or any other direct jdbc connector)?

Comment: probably no measurable difference. JdbcTemplate is more suited to the task of scrolling through results without loading everything in memory.